# Rails/Haml error: undefined method `-@' for "":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a Haml template for a Rails app that consistently hits this error in production, though never in development.

My template starts like this:

```
= simple_form_for :foo, url: { action: :update }, method: :patch do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :arr_field2 do |f_field_arr|  -# create an array
    = f.error_notification
    .padded
      - @foo.arr_field.each_with_index do |item, i|
        .control-group
          ...
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for "":String
```

The error message claims the issue is on line 3 of the template, but when I remove

`= f.error_notification`

the error still occurs, and still claims the issue is line 3. Has anyone run into anything similar?

To give a bit of context, `@foo` exists (I've checked), and has an array of strings (`arr_field`). The point of the form is getting the user to set other fields (`arr_field2`) to match the fields in `arr_field`.

Comment: Try removing '-' sign just before # line above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, right there:

```
= simple_form_for :foo, url: { action: :update }, method: :patch do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :arr_field2 do |f_field_arr|  -# create an array
                                                      ^
                                                      # right here
```

This dash should be after the comment sign to not be interpreted by Ruby:

```
= simple_form_for :foo, url: { action: :update }, method: :patch do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :arr_field2 do |f_field_arr|  #- create an array
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had misunderstood the role of the dash and equals signs in Haml.